# Is it considered good practise to have jQuery scripts in a PHP conditional?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, conditional-statements

I have several jQuery scripts that are used on my website, but not on every page. I place these scripts in a PHP conditional so that it only outputs them on the required pages.

Now what I'm wondering is: is this considered good practice? Does this speed up the website? Are there even any positive aspects to using this method?

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?>

    <script>
        //jQuery code
        //jQuery code
        //jQuery code
    </script>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You might do this if the script is not always required, though equally you could just output a conditional JS file asset. If the user is likely to use this page only once, you can do it inline as you suggest, but otherwise (even if it is conditional) you may wish to use an asset, so it benefits from browser-side caching.

Comment: The only improvement I would suggest making is using `wp_register_script()` and `wp_enqueue_script()` and ensuring this is in your functions.php.

Comment: Write your jquery in a separate js page ex: custom-jquery.js and then include it using if(is_home()) { wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-jquery', 'js/custom-jquery.js'); }. Write this line of code in functions.php of your theme.

Comment: What Pranita said is a good practice, however, it depends on the complexity of your project. If are going to spend weeks on a project then you should consider not having these sorts of inline <script> tags as it makes coding a horrifying experience further on. If you have a few pages that needs js, then there is no reason to do anything other than what you did, especially if you have less than 100 lines of js that don't work with dom much, but calculate dates and stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though there is nothing ***wrong*** with doing this you are giving up browser-side caching for a minor temporary convenience. I say temporary because this is definitely not something I would deploy on a larger scale system.

The reason browser-side caching is being given up is because a PHP file is always requested fresh by the browser because it is assumed to have dynamic data.

I would recommend a `/assets/js/pages/home.js` layout for your JS files which get conditionally included as an external file because this will be much more scalable in the future:

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?>

    <script src="/assets/js/pages/home.js"></script>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I am using this for some really small scale AJAX calls so for now this will work fine. I will be working on bigger projects in the future though so I'll keep this in mind! Thanks for teaching me something new :)

Comment: Glad I could help guide you in the right direction! Let me know if you want to see an excellent usage example of the assets layout I mentioned above.